# Customize `simplify` in Sympy to give output in a desired format, with powers of 2 combined

Tags: sympy

I want to simplify an expression using the `simplify` function in `sympy`, and want output in special format

```
simplify("2*((2**n)+1)**2").expand(Basic=True)
```

However, `sympy` is returning me the following result:

```
2*2**(2*n) + 4*2**n + 2
```

But I want the result in the following format:

```
2**(2*n+1) + 2**(n+2) + 2
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy's [simplify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html) module offers several methods of simplification: the one you need here is [powsimp](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#powsimp).

```
from sympy import *
var('n')
a = simplify(2*((2**n)+1)**2).expand(Basic=True)
powsimp(a)
```

output: `2**(n + 2) + 2**(2*n + 1) + 2`